# Custom login functionality on a Site page

Tags: force.com-sites, authentication

**Trying to achieve**: Custom login on our SF Public Site page for a sub-set of users within our org. to access a form. Submitting the data would update a Case record. Each form would be one-time submission and reopening the form after submission would result in read-only content.

For example:

URL #1: [www.ourSalesforceInstanceSitePage.com/caseId=0054343casda11/](http://www.ourSalesforceInstanceSitePage.com/caseId=0054343casda11/)

Clicking on it for the first time opens up a form with the Case record data. The user who opened the page would be submitting some data that would ultimately update the underlying Case record. If the user tries to reopen the URL, it would be read-only content of the submission.

For this Site page, we are trying implement some sort of authentication so that we can connect the Case record's audit fields to the user who accessed the URL.

**Questions:**

1. We are familiar that Site page come with a guest user profile, but, can we implement a custom login that reads unique ID data from a custom object?
2. We are not going down the path of a Community for obvious reasons, budget issues. So, can we achieve the Case-User connectivity with the Site pages?

Any insights are most welcome.

Update:
I am planning to take a path with complete custom login implementation using one custom object as back-end source for user authentication (storing username/password). Can someone suggest if there's a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "a sub-set of users within our org"?  Do you mean people within your company who do not have user licenses?

Comment: I would ask to check the implementation with SF Account manager, while not intentional it looks like it will be violating SF platform EULA. `: I am planning to take a path with complete custom login implementation using one custom object as back-end source for user authentication (storing username/password)`

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

1. We are familiar that Site page come with a guest user profile, but,
   can we implement a custom login that reads unique ID data from a
   custom object?

> Not recommended. you can look at [authenticated high volume community
> or site users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5) license. By building a custom login functionality you
> are violating the Salesforce MSA and if they find this out on review it will have repercussions.

2. We are not going down the path of a Community for obvious reasons,
   budget issues. So, can we achieve the Case-User connectivity with
   the Site pages?

> you can try using without sharing apex class and see if it works. From
> what i know case creation as guest user is possible but not user if
> edit functionality on case works. Either ways i would try to get the
> cheapest community license to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what you're trying to do but if users have no license and you don't want to violate SF terms here's something you can do, unless you really need to use SF Public site :

- create a connected app
- create a page/minisite *outside* Salesforce, ie. on a LAMP server or any kind you like
- authenticate your page users the way you like (custom, SSO, webservice to salesforce...)
- use REST API to get / update your cases
- store user's username (or a hash of it, or his id...) in a custom field on the case

If there's no username on the case display the form, if there's one (an if it matches current user, or not depending what you want) just display read-only data.